# What does VS Code editor.overviewRulerLanes setting does?

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

I can't figure out what the `"editor.overviewRulerLanes": 3` setting does, as it does not change the number of lanes in the overview ruler and I can't find an answer anywhere, including VS Code's documentation.

`"editor.overviewRulerLanes": 0` shows this:

[image]

What is `"editor.overviewRulerLanes"` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting doesn't do anything in VS Code. There must be some piece of code somewhere that always sets that value to 3. I think the setting should be removed from the JSON schema.

In the editor powering VS Code (which ships as the Monaco Editor) and can be executed at https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html , the setting `overviewRulerLanes` does have effect. For example `overviewRulerLanes: 1` reduces the "vertical lanes" from 3 to 1 and makes all the rendered decorations look wider:

[image: An image showing how the overview ruler gets rendered when the overviewRulerLanes is configured to be equal to 1]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83186) in VS Code's GitHub.